# Compiling Jose4j .93 with JDK 8. I am getting errors when compling .93 Jose4j. Anyone knows how to fix this JDK 17 works

Tags: java-8, compiler-errors, jose4j

Unable to compile Jose4j .93 with JDK 8

I tried compiling Jose4j .93. version with JDK 8

It works with JDK 17.

My requirement is to compile and run it on JDK 8.

Are there are guidelines to compile with JDK 8.

How to bypass these errors :

cannot find symbol
symbol:   class EdECPrivateKey
location: package java.security.interfaces
[ERROR] /scratch/jose0.9.3/b_c-jose4j-b5720a2fde3f/src/main/java/org/jose4j/jws/EdDsaAlgorithm.java:[10,32] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class EdECPublicKey

Answer (score 0):

It's compiled on 17 but targeted for 1.7 so will run on 8 fine. You shouldn't need to compile it yourself.